# What is wrong with following resolution where the Higgs Field emerges without breaking any symmetry?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, higgs

Given a real field $\phi(x, t)$ that describe the magnetization of an unidimensional iron bar:

$$
\textit{L} = \frac{1}{2} \rho \left( \frac{1}{v^2} \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} ^2 \right) \right) - \frac{1}{2}\alpha(T - T_0)\phi ^2
 - \frac{1}{4} \beta \phi ^4 
$$
where $\alpha$  and $\beta$ are positive constants

If I suppose that $T > T_0$, I have a stable point for the potential $\phi_0 = 0$.

Moreover, if I expand the potential around $\phi_0$ and calculate the Lagrangian in the surroundings of this point ($\phi \approx \phi_0 + \eta$), I have:

$$
\textit{L} = \frac{1}{2} \rho \left( \frac{1}{v^2} \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} ^2 \right) \right) - \frac{1}{2}\alpha(T - T_0)\phi ^2
$$

In this case, there isn't a spontaneous break of the discrete symmetry $Z_2$ (which occurs if T > $T_0$) but I still have the last term which corresponds to the Higgs Field  I suppose, which does not make any sense.

Could someone explain me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "the Higgs field" in this context? The field here is just your field, which has a positive mass squared for $T > T_0$.

Comment: @Javier It is an expansio of the potential around \phi_0 which is equal in this case. 
for the case T <  T_0, my professor called it the Higgs Field around an equilibium \neq 0. But in that situation, there was a break of Z_2 symmetry for the equilibium point